# My pictures won't load in articles in joomla Version 1.5.26

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla1.5, photos

I have added a picture to my webpage here http://www.backpacks4aussiekids.com.au/Home.html and it works just fine, but when I tried the same thing in an article here http://www.backpacks4aussiekids.com.au/Articles/what-is-needed.html  the pix won't load, even though I followed the same proceedure.

I even tried changing the pix from .jpg to .png and back again. The only way the changes can be viewed is if I clear my site and browser cache before I attempt to view the site.

All the text is able to be viewed but there are either empty boxes where the pix should be or nothing at all.
thanks in advance, des

Comment: How do you embed the picture? Are you using an editor or plain HTML code? What procedure are you following? ...and why all your images are within `input` tags?

Answer (score 0):

The image definitely exists as I have checked.

The reason why it's not showing is because the picture on the homepage is within an `<img>` tag where as the picture on the second link you provided is for some reason within an `<input>` tag as shown below:

```
<input type="image" style="width: 511px; height: 684px; float: left;" src="http://backpacks4aussiekids.com.au/images/what we need now/clipboard 1.png" alt="">
```

Open the article in the article manager, click on the little `html` button which will open a window, find the code above and change to the following:

```
<img style="width: 511px; height: 684px; float: left;" src="http://backpacks4aussiekids.com.au/images/what we need now/clipboard 1.png" alt="" />
```

Hope this helps